# how can i recursively rename folders in windows matching string and ignoring case

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, file-rename

I have subfolders which have names:

- original_Optimize
- Original_optimize
- original_optimize
- Original_Optimize

I would like to rename all of these to:

- **Original_Optimize**

Is there an easy way of doing this in windows (perhaps using powershell or something in command prompt ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in two Rename-Item calls. The first would add a prefix to each name to avoid the 'Source and destination path must be different.' error. The second run will remove the prefix.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter original_optimize -Recurse | 
Rename-Item -NewName __foo__Original_Optimize -PassThru | 
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '^__foo__'} -PassThru
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with powershell. However, does this command take care of case insensitivity for `original_opTimize` ?

Comment: Yes it does, casing is not an issue since by nature PowerShell is not case-sensitive. You can verify it with this: Get-ChildItem -Filter original_optimize -Recurse. You should get all folders.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\path-to-directory -Recurse -Filter *foo* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace 'foo', 'bar'} -verbose
```